# read file from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get a file from s3 bucket with golang. What's special in my request is that I need to get a file from the root of the s3. i.e, in my situation, i have a buckets folder which is the root for the s3, inside that i have folders and files. I need to get the files from the buckets folder. it means that i don't have a bucket folder because i access only to the root.
the code im trying is:

```
numBytes, err := downloader.Download(file, &s3.GetObjectInput{
  Bucket: aws.String("/"),
  Key:   aws.String("some_image.jpeg"),
})
```

The problem is I got an error that says the object does not exist.
Is it possible to read files from the root of s3? What do I need to write in the bucket? the key is written okay?

Many thanks for helping!

Comment: You have to specify the bucket name to read the object. The key is part which allows folder like addressing.

Comment: I tried to put on the Bucket the value “buckets”, I thought maybe if I will give the root folder it will work but I still got the same error… what you mean is I only can read files from a bucket folder and not from the root?

Comment: Example: Bucket: "mybucket", Key: "dogs/snoopy.png".

Answer (score 1):

All files in S3 are stored inside buckets. You're not able to store a file in the root of s3.

Each bucket is its own distinct namespace. You can have multiple buckets in your Amazon account, and each file must belong to one of those buckets.

You can either create a bucket using the AWS web interface, command line tools or API. (Or 3rd party software like Cyberduck).

You can read more about buckets in S3 here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingBucket.html

Comment: I’m using on seaweedFS which allow me to upload files into the root folder. The question it’s can I read the files I upload to the root folder?

Comment: Yes definitely - you can read a file that was uploaded into the root of the bucket. In that case, you will need to adjust your code to include the correct bucket name.

(As an aside, S3 doesn't actually have folders in the traditional sense - each file has its own distinct name. It's mainly just a convention that the slash '/' is used as a delimiter to simulate a directory structure)

Comment: i tried to put on the bucket name the value "buckets" which mean the root of the storage but it didnt worked. do you know which convention i need to make it work in the meaning of bucket value and key value in the code?

Comment: You need to add the actual name of your bucket. It is not possible to have a bucket without a name. You can either log in to the AWS web console, or use a program like Cyberduck, to view your buckets. That should tell you the name of the bucket you created. (Or, if you haven't created one yet, you can create one there too)